# change color of navigation bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I change the color of navigation bar from its default blue color?

Thanks.

Comment: This is very close to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901542/using-image-or-tint-color-on-uinavigationbar-in-iphone

Answer (score 4):

The `UINavigationBar` class has a `UIColor *tintColor` property that you can change in code.

Alternately this property is also exposed in the InterfaceBuilder UI design tool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you pls let me know if I can use an image as navigation bar background?

Comment: To set it to an image you could try use a pattern for your UIColor:

UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: patternImage];
yourNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = myColor;

I've not tried this, so YMMV.  If it doesn't work, you'll have to subclass the UINavigationBar (Not the simplest of tasks).

Comment: @pixel The UINavigationBar seems unwilling to accept a UIColor made with colorWithPatternImage, unfortunately. That seems to produce a black navigation bar.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have added the navigation bar programmatically and not in Interface Builder, just put this in your viewDidLoad method.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

TintColor property doesn't affect default subview of navigation bar as bottom border and shadow. Sometimes it's useful to override layout of navigation bar at all.

Despite navigationBar is read-only property for UINavigationController you can avoid
this restriction by "setValue:forKey:". This method was approved on 5 applications successfully submitted to AppStore.

You can subclass UINavigationBar and change drawRect: method as you want.
For example,

```
@implementation CustomNavigationBar

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = ImageFromColor(WANTED_COLOR);
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:rect];
}
```

After you can subclass UINavigationController and change initWithRootViewController:

```
- (id) initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController]; 
    if (self) 
    {
        CustomNavigationBar *navBar = [CustomNavigationBar new];
        [self setValue:navBar forKey:@"navigationBar"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also you can vary this approach by making Category for UINavigationController and implementing method swizzling for initWithRootViewController:

P.S. Yesterday my new app appeared at AppStore without any problem with this approach.