# Custom UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I want have a custom navigationbar .But there is a white space between navigationbar and status bar.The code is below:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage) 
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have solved the question.I will give the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867827/how-to-move-from-custom-to-transluscent-navigationbar-and-back-display-problems)

Answer (score 3):

Do not override methods in categories.

Do **NOT** override metods in categories.

### DO NOT OVERRIDE METHODS IN CATEGORIES.

Now that that is out of the way.

This just means that your image has the white line in it, or your navigation bar is placed incorrectly.

Comment: hi,there is no white line in image .And in fact ,I don't deal with the navigationbar ,i use the navigationcontroller and the drawrect method will draw the picture in the navigationbar automatically. Thanks.

Comment: What a simple hint but overly important.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be necessarily in navigation bar. The frame of the navigation controller or view controller may not have been set properly.

There are chances that the navigation controller or view controller leaves space for `status bar` or `navigation bar` without having any idea about whether they are already there or not.

Make sure you are creating the navigation controller or view controller with proper `frames`.

Comment: I have using the same method in apple samples but the white space exists too.

Comment: Try to set `navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);`